# Mapping geo-location (coordinates or city) to WorldBank climate API river basin id

Tags: xml, r, google-maps, geolocation, weather-api

I'm interested in historical average temperatures on the city level. [WorldBank climate API](http://data.worldbank.org/developers/climate-data-api) provides such historical data on the country or [river basin](http://data.worldbank.org/sites/default/files/climate_data_api_basins.pdf) level. Country level is too course for me. River basin level would be very good, but I haven't found a way how to convert geo-coordinate to river basins ids to map cities to the river basins. Shape files of the basins are provided by [waterbase.org](http://www.waterbase.org/download_data.html#id10). Any help to map geo-coordinates to WorldBank river basin ids is welcome.

Comment: while i have not done any modding yet, i fear that without some R code to show this will be closed as too broad a topic.

Comment: too broad topic? I have latitude and longitude and I would like to map it to river basin id.

Comment: well, yes, since you've provided zero code for anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite lack of originating code, here's how you can get a complete `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` with a `basin_id` associated with each polygon.

One part of their API lets you specify a basin ID and that returns a KML file of the region. So you can query all of them and stick'em together:

```
library(httr)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(pbapply)

basin_list <- pblapply(1:468, function(basin_id) {

  res <- GET(sprintf("http://climatedataapi.worldbank.org/climateweb/rest/v1/basin/kml/%d", basin_id))
  fil <- tempfile(fileext=".xml")
  writeLines(content(res, as="text"), fil)
  kml <- readOGR(fil, "Layer #0", verbose=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  unlink(fil)
  kml$basin_id = basin_id
  # these are useless
  kml$Name <- kml$Description <-NULL
  kml

})

basin_list <- c(basin_list, makeUniqueIDs=TRUE)
basins <- do.call(rbind, basin_list)
basins@data

##    basin_id
## 0         1
## 01        2
## 02        3
## 03        4
## 04        5
## 05        6
## 06        7
## 07        8
## 08        9
## 09       10
```

Obviously I didn't sit for many minutes for all 468, just 10 of them.

> *(Actually, I let it run while doing other work and saved you the trouble of having to generate the files. You can get them at [this github repo](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/basins))*

To see that it is getting all the basins:

```
plot(basins)
```

[image]

There is an issue with topology errors from the giant data frame, so if you do need to determine which polygon a particular lat/lon pair is in (so you can map it to a basin id) then you have to kinda work at it a bit:

```
library(rgeos)

# pick a random point in basin 3
spot <- spsample(basin_list[[3]], 1, "random")

# now try to find it in reverse
which(sapply(1:468, function(i) gContains(basin_list[[i]], spot)))
```

These aren't complex polygons so it's pretty fast.

Others may have time to simplify this a bit (i.e. correct rbinded polygon topology errors).

Also, please consider being kind to the WorldBank API server and doing both:

```
save(basin_list, basins, file="basins.rda")
```

and

```
writeOGR(basins, ".", "basins", driver="ESRI Shapefile")
# or 
geojsonio::geojson_write(basins, geometry="polygon", group="basin_id", "basins.json")
```

so you have the data sets locally and do not need to recreate them.